# Creating a DLL for Drawing a Rectangle in VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net, graphics, modularity

## About the Project

I have a form that has three buttons, each add a rectangle to the drawing area of the form (SplitContainer.Panel2). As you can see, adding this code multiple times to different buttons becomes very tedious and cluttering. I was wanting to know if I could call a function to perform this code. I know how to create functions and how to call them, but I **do not** understand how to reference the controls within the forms (e.g the panel).

**Screenshot of the project (after clicking a few buttons):**

http://i61.tinypic.com/2q9kr5y.png (low rep, had to use URL)

## My Code Called From the "Add Move" Button:

```
Dim objGraphics As Graphics
    Dim rect = New Rectangle(intX, intY, 50, 50)
    Dim objFont As Font
    Dim objFont2 As Font
    Dim intFontSize As Integer = 12
    Dim intTextX As Integer = intX
    Dim intTextY As Integer = intY

    ' Create a graphics object using the memory bitmap
    objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(m_objDrawingSurface)

    objGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Plum, rect)
    objGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)

    objFont = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", intFontSize, _
                                      FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)

    objFont2 = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", intFontSize - 5, _
                                      FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)

    ' Draw user's text
    objGraphics.DrawString("Move", objFont, _
                           System.Drawing.Brushes.White, intTextX, intTextY)

    objGraphics.DrawString("(" & MousePosition.X & ", " & MousePosition.Y & ")", objFont2, _
                           System.Drawing.Brushes.White, intTextX, intTextY + 17)


    ' Clean up
    objGraphics.Dispose()

    ' Force the form to paint itself. This triggers the Paint Event
    SplitContainer1.Panel2.Invalidate()

    intX += 50

    If intX >= SplitContainer1.Panel2.Width Then
        intY += 50
        intX = 0
    End If
```

## The Goal

I want to be able to separate my code in a more modular fashion. I'm coming from C++ where modulation is everything, and without here, my code grows enormously. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To be straight forward, how can I replicate this code in a Class Library or DLL so that I can use it in a modular fashion?

Comment: I'd recommend creating a function that takes the panel as an argument, and then calling it for each panel in the split container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A DLL is a bit overkill IMHO**.

But I'm wondering : if you *can* create a function, you *should* be able to compile a DLL containing that function... What is the issue ?

Creating a Function is very simple, assuming your function gets access to the control object, ie, the SplitContainer.Panel2, or any other ***defined*** control (Button, Panel, etc.) you want to alter the painting. **ie, you have to pass that control to the function.**

```
Public Function DrawRectangleOn(ByRef SplitContainerPanel As SplitterPanel) As Boolean
    ' ... Do the drawings.
```

If you have some layout conditions, you must pass the criterias to control those conditions **aswell**.

```
Public Function DrawRectangleOn( _
    ByRef SplitContainerPanel As SplitterPanel, _
    ByVal PlotX As Int32, _
    ByVal PlotY As Int32, _
    ByVal FrameColor As Color, _
    ByVal FrameBackground As Color, _
    ByVal Caption As String, _
    ByVal MousePosX As Int32, _
    ByVal MousePosY As Int32, _
    ByVal ... etc. etc. etc.) As Boolean
    ' ... Do the drawings.
```

You don't have to use a `Function` (in VB meaning) but a `Method` if you don't need to get a return/result value of the operation :

```
Public Sub DrawRectangleOn( ... )
```

---

One thing however, your Function/Method should know what's the Type of the object to manipulate. That means, if you want to manipulate several controls, you'll have to  :

**a)** either make several function with stronged types parameters :

```
Public Function DrawRectangleOn(ByRef SplitContainerPanel As SplitterPanel, ...)
Public Overloads Function DrawRectangleOn(ByRef ControlButton As Button, ...)
Public Overloads Function DrawRectangleOn(ByRef ControlPanel As Panel, ...)
```

**b)** or define the type of the object inside that function by passing a *weak* type parameter :

```
Public Function DrawRectangleOn(ByRef PassedControl As Control, ...)
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf(PassedControl) Is SplitterPanel:
            Dim ControlSplitterPanel As SplitterPanel = _
                DirectCast(PassedControl, SplitterPanel)
            ' ... Manipulate a SplitterPanel here.

            Return True

        Case TypeOf(PassedControl) Is Button:
            Dim ControlButton As Button = _
                DirectCast(PassedControl, Button)
            ' ... Manipulate a Button here.

            Return True

        Case Else:
            Throw New ArgumentException("Unable to handle Object of type " + PassedControl.GetType().ToString())

    End Select
End Function
```

---

If you create a DLL, I'm sure you're aware that each time you make changes to the source of that DLL, you'll have to recompile it and redistribute it in order to update any project/solution/application using it. A DLL ought to be the ultimate goal of the work, and should be well envisioned before writing the code, not decided as a requirement you would think of in the middle of the coding.

That's why I said a DLL is a bit overkill XD. DLLs (should) have version numbering and should backward compatibles, otherwise you'll have unpredictable behaviours in previous applications using them...

---

I'm somewhat curious : what do you want to do with all that custom drawn frames ?

All you're doing now is drawing on the control. But it would make sense to be able to click on the *rectangles/frames* and call specific methods/functions... it would also make sense to notify the user when the mouse is above one frame, like changing the frame background for example...

=> I'm not telling you to implement the above. You don't have to answer the question above, what you want to do is up to you. I'm just telling you to define ***every feature that should be considered before deciding what tools you're going to use*** (ie *how are you going to write code, which components to use, etc.*)

There are other approaches you can experiment :

- Create a `CustomSplitContainer` that **inherits** from `SplitContainer`. Then handle the UI inside by adding public methods and function and properties and events.
- Create a `UserControl` from scratch with a `SplitContainer` then handle the UI behaviour inside, or just like above, create public members to be able to control the UI externaly.
- Create Control `Extensions` (*System.Runtime.CompilerServices* - User defined Functions and Methods extended on an instanciated object/control - requires the appropriate dotNet Framework)
- Create a `Public Module` with members you can call from anywhere in your project.
- Create a `custom Class` which constructor gets reference to the Control to handle. Then, handle every click, mouseover, etc. and draw the appropriate UI from inside that class.
- (... like using delegates)

The custom class example is the one I'm using most : I know everything I need is within that class that does only what it's supposed to do with strong typed members. And there are Control Members I usually don't need to take care of, while, for precise and repetitive tasks like altering the UI, it's easier to encapsulate the control in a class, and create persistant properties, methods, functions and events. Upon instanciation, AddHandler is very usefull to capture mouse and keyboard inputs, handle custom drag/drops, etc. (However, those custom classes should be properly destroyed when not required anylonger)

---

Anyway, you can write the code of a DLL whatever your choice.

- Create a project by selecting **"Class Library"** <- this would answer your question..
- Copy the code you've done in that library project with the appropriate or required changes (that's what I said above : you must pass any required references to the functions of that DLL)
- Build it
- Locate the DLL in your Debug/Release folder of current project
- Copy it to your final project that will use the DLL
- Imports the reference the usual way.

or just add a class library sub project in your solution.

Just make sure to select the best approach to reach your goal. You can always add links to classes/modules sources in any project/solution and reuse an already available code **without creating a DLL** ! The code is just compiled in your executable.

PS : by the way, if you were/are C++, I would advise you to go on with C#.

Comment: Excellent advise, I applaud your in-depth answer as well. This greatly helped me decide what I wanted to implement within the project :) cheers.